# Spark SQL error..org.datanucleus" is already registered

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read JSON file using spark SQL in spark-shell but getting error. I am new to Spark SQL

I create sparksession as below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

 val spark = SparkSession.builder()
  .master("local")
  .appName("Spark SQL Practice")
  .getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._
```

After that I am trying to read JSON file

```
val df = spark.read.json("D:/Lectures/11_Nov_day16_spark.day5/people.json")
```

```
> scala val df = spark.read.json("D:/Lectures/11_Nov_day16_spark.day5/people.json")

 19/08/06 18:54:53 WARN General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus" is
 already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the
 same plugin in the classpath. The URL
 "file:/C:/spark/jars/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar" is already
 registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located
 at URL "file:/C:/spark/bin/../jars/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar."

 19/08/06 18:54:53 WARN General: Plugin (Bundle)
 "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms" is already registered. Ensure you dont
 have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The
 URL "file:/C:/spark/bin/../jars/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar" is
 already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin
 located at URL "file:/C:/spark/jars/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar."

 19/08/06 18:54:53 WARN General: Plugin (Bundle)
 "org.datanucleus.api.jdo" is already registered. Ensure you dont have
 multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL
 "file:/C:/spark/bin/../jars/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar" is already
 registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located
 at URL "file:/C:/spark/jars/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar." 

 19/08/06 18:55:00 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database default, returning
 NoSuchObjectException
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the Dependency tree of your project and remove all duplicate dependency of the `datanucleus` or add the same datanucleus-core dependency to the plugin-config.

Thanks

Comment: How to do that? I am new to spark SQL

Comment: @pravingaikwad Please run this command `sbt "inspect tree clean"` then you will find clean tree and then exclude the duplicate dependency.